# AFNetworkinf 2.0 json

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, post, afnetworking-2

i'm using AFnetworking 2.0 Obj-c, i'm using manager POST method with json 
the problem is the format of the json with v2.0 is not right it's always 
something like 
`{"data" = "{"name":"name" , "age" :"30"}"}`
but the format i want is full json like 
`{"data" : "{"name":"name" , "age" : "30"}"}`

my code is:

```
`NSDictionary* dateDic = @{ @"data" : data };
AuthorizationResponse* authResponse = [[AuthorizationResponse alloc] init];
//creating connction manager
//[AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager* manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializerWithWritingOptions:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted];

AFJSONRequestSerializer* requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
manager.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;
[manager POST:URL parameters:dateDic success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation, id responseObject) {
    onSuccess(responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation, NSError* error) {
    //ICityError icity = [[ICityError alloc] init]
    ICityErrorItem* errorManager = [[ICityErrorItem alloc] init];
    [errorManager setCode:error.code];
    [errorManager setDescription:error.description];
    onError(errorManager);
}];
```

dateDic should be the dic to be parsed as json but it show me the issue i wrote

please if you answer try to give me sample of code as im new with iOS 
thanks in advance

Comment: Please put your code also in your question where you are posting the json. Elaborate a bit.

Comment: What is data in this. Is that another object? @{ @"data" : data }; and what code it is poiniting to?

Comment: @Jassi data is json as nsstring

Comment: Okay give that string data directly in palce of data object. You are passing a string to the dictionary. You are creating json yourself which is not correct.

Comment: @Jassi you mean give the string directly to the parameters ?

Comment: Yes. NSDictionary* dateDic = @{ @"data" : @{"name":"name" , "age" : "30"} };

Comment: @Jassi the problem is not the string the problem is the format after data it become data =  data not data : data

Comment: Okay, so you are getting that data in the request parameter in your web service?

Comment: @Jassi yes but not right format there was sol for that in ver 1 but not anymore

Comment: I have written the code last night to send data to server. I have a php script that accepts the json data. It is wotking fine. I will add an aswer with the code

Comment: Please find below answer with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the code below to send JSON data from iOS to PHP using AFNetworking framework. Here is the github link for reference: [Github link](https://github.com/jassionly4u/TestingAFNetworking-JSON/)

I have used Pod to install AFNetworking. You can do so by using the Ray's [Cocoa Pods link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64546/introduction-to-cocoapods-2).

You need to setup XAMPP server on your MAC machine to access the PHP. Download XAMPP server from [XAMPP download link](https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/5.6.3/xampp-osx-5.6.3-0-installer.dmg)

Once XAMPP is downloaded and you have installed it. Run it. After that go to folder: Applications->XAMPP->xamppfiles->htdocs

Create a new folder named - "Testing"

Create a PHP file named "testJson.php" in XCode or any editor. Keep the extension of the file as PHP. And save that file in "Testing" folder. Once this is done. Run the project from XCode. And you will find whatever data you are sending. You will get back the data in JSON. Do not worry if it displays on console with "=" and not with ":". It is an `NSDictionary` and you can get the value using the `valueForKey:` or `valueForKeyPath:` or `objectForKeyPath:` methods.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);

header('Content-Type:application/json');
$jsonencode = json_encode($obj);
echo $jsonencode;

?>
```

You can send JSON data by two ways in iOS using AFNetworking

Method1:

```
- (void)method1
{
// Method 1

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager* manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializerWithWritingOptions:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted];
[manager.responseSerializer setAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObjects:@"text/plain",@"application/json",@"text/html",nil]];

NSDictionary *dateDic = @{@"data":@{@"name":@"name", @"age":@"40"}};

[manager POST:@"http://localhost/Testing/testJson.php" parameters:dateDic success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"response %@",responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation, NSError* error) {
    NSLog(@"eror %@",error);

}];
}
```

Method 2:

```
- (void)method2
{
// Method 2
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializerWithWritingOptions:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted];
[manager.responseSerializer setAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObjects:@"text/plain",@"application/json",@"text/html",nil]];
NSDictionary *dateDic = @{@"data":@{@"name":@"name", @"age":@"40"}};

[manager POST:@"http://localhost/Testing/testJson.php"
   parameters:dateDic
      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
          NSLog(@"response %@",responseObject);
          NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

          NSLog(@"dict %@",[dict valueForKeyPath:@"data.age"]);

      }
      failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
          NSLog(@"eror %@",error);
      }];
}
```

You can call both these methods one by one from `viewDidLoad:` The output will be same.

Comment: the problem was in http request not in the response but than˚ you your answer helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

The parameter data, is string?

And if you try with this sintax?

```
NSDictionary *parametros = @{@"data":data};

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager POST:url parameters:parametros success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    for (NSDictionary *nsdValue in responseObject[@"data"]){
    NSLog(@"name %@, age %@", nsdValue[@"name"], nsdValue[@"age"]);         
    }

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

}];
```

Comment: no difference between it and what i did also i used same steps with another networ˚ing api and it wor˚ fine dont dont ˚now what is the issue with afnetwro˚ing 2.0